# How do I keep animations from flickering in C# game programming?

Tags: c#

Everytime I try to add a new line or move the paddle in this game the screen flickers.

How do I keep the screen from flickering when I move the paddle or add a line?

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class GameTest : Form
{
    int dx=3, dy=3, i =500, o = 100;

   int rex = 400, rey = 450 ;
       double c =0;


    public GameTest()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {

            //Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();


            Invalidate();
            Brush black = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            g.FillRectangle(black, rex, rey, 200, 20);

            rex -= 40;
            Brush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            g.FillRectangle(red, rex, rey, 200, 20);




        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {


            //Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();



            Brush white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            g.FillRectangle(white, rex, rey, 200, 20);

            rex += 40;
            Brush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            g.FillRectangle(red, rex, rey, 200, 20);

        }
    }



    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = false;

         Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
         //  Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap("G:\c#\Bouncing ball\Pic.jpg");
        //TextureBrush tb2 = new TextureBrush(bmp1);

        Brush green = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            g.FillRectangle(green, rex, rey, 200, 20);

            Graphics b= this.CreateGraphics();

            Brush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

            b.FillEllipse(red, i, o, 20, 20);



       Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 10);
        //
           g.DrawLine(p, 1000, 480,0,480);
          g.DrawLine(p, 1000, 485, 1000, 0);

        g .DrawLine(p, 0,480, 0, 0);
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = false;
        //  int dx=3, dy=3, i = 300, o = 50;

        i += dx;


        if (i < 0)
        {
            dx = -dx;
        }

        else if (i + 50 > 1000)
        {
            dx = -dx;
        }



        o += dy;

        if ((o +20>= rey) &&(i+20<=rex+200)&&(i+20>=rex))
        {
            //int rex = 400, rey = 450; RECTANGLE
            // int dx=3, dy=3, i(x) = 500, o(y) = 100;

            dy =-dy;
            //c++;
            //label1.Text = c.ToString();
        }


            // Misgeret\\
            if (o < 0)
            {
                dy = -dy;
            }
            // Misgeret\\
            else if (o + 50 > 600)
            {
                dy = -dy;
            }
           this.Invalidate();



    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = c.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you use this `DoubleBuffered = false;`?

Comment: winforms doesn't support animations, and is not an appropiate platform for game development, nor for anything else I can think of. Use `WPF` for Windows UIs and `XNA` for C# game development, or straight `C++` DirectX hardcore stuff for serious games.

Comment: You are creating ***a lot*** of disposable objects and not properly handling them. You will be getting `OutOfMemoryException` errors fairly quickly if you let your program run for any amount of time. You really should not be creating any graphics objects at all and be doing all your work using the graphics property passed in to the `Paint` events.

Comment: Sir if you dont mind can you please fix the mistakes It will really help me and its for a school project thats why i am doing it on GIB*

Comment: You keep asking questions on this site but it keeps making new users for you (I know i have seen several questions about this same game you are writing (that or your classmates are asking the same questions)). Please log in and make an account if you plan on keep asking questions

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that you are setting `DoubleBuffered` to false in multiple areas of your program. That is definitely not helping since the whole reason to use double buffering is to prevent flickering.

The other thing is you are creating Graphics contexts and drawing in multiple places in your application. Try to refactor your code to only draw in the `OnPaint()` event handler of the form, and do not create a new Graphics context. Use the one provided in the `PaintEventArgs` of the `OnPaint()` event.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    using(Brush green = new SolidBrush(Color.Green))
    {
         g.FillRectangle(green, rex, rey, 200, 20);
    }

    // .. etc, etc..        
}
```

Then, when you need to the form to be repainted you just need to invoke the `Invalidate()` method to tell the GDI that your form, or a portion of it, needs to be repainted. That will in turn cause the `Paint` event to be fired and the `OnPaint()` to be called.

As a side note, as @HighCore suggested in the comments, WinForms is definitely not the right framework to create a game in. For games try the XNA framework, or one of several open source ones available on the web such as [Unity](http://unity3d.com/)

**UPDATE**

To prevent flickering you can use automatic double buffering for your form. This can be enabled in the form constructor, after the call to `InitializeComponent()`, using a call to `SetStyle`:

```
 SetStyle( ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint
         | ControlStyles.UserPaint
         | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer , true);
```

Comment: Do **NOT** dispose `e.Graphics`, only dispose of a graphics object if you created it, if it was passed as a property of another object (`PaintEventArgs`) you need to let the parent dispose it (however you really **should** be disposing of that `Brush` object you created).

Comment: ya I made it false cuz at first it was on true and it started to flickering even more

Comment: @user2985089 it is flickering even more because you are supposed to use the paint event not calling CreateGraphics all over the place. The un-overriden Paint call blanks the page, then you redraw your stuff on top of it, subscribing to the Paint event and doing your drawing there should fix that .

Comment: I am really sorry if I am being stupid because I really dont know how to do that maybe I will start learning again thx for help tho

Comment: @user2985089 - as Scott said, once you move all your drawing logic inside the Paint event handler, and after you enable double buffering the flicker should go away.